# Getting the state with rematch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rematch

I am learning rematch/redux. I can't get the state to show with the API.
I have the model imported in `index.js` along with the store and the provider. These are my reducers/effects:

```js
import { getItems } from './service'

const products = {
  state: {
    products: [],
  },

  reducers: {
    setProducts(state, products) {
      return {
        ...state,
        products,
      };
    },
  },
  effects: {
    async loadProducts() {
      const products = await getItems() // <-- This is the api working normally
      this.setProducts(products)
    },
  }

}

export default products
```

And this is my component:

```js
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const mapStateToProps = ({ products }) => {
  return {
    ...products
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = ({ products }) => {
  return {
    ...products
  }
}

const App = ({ products }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(products)
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(products)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Thank you.

Comment: Never used rematch before, but I don't see where you are calling `loadProducts`? I was expecting to seeing something like `useEffect(() => {products.loadProducts()}, [])` or something in `App`

Answer (score 1):

I'm Rematch maintainer, you should review our documentation or consider buying the official Redux made easy with Rematch book where you'll learn all this questions.

I highly recommend using React-Redux hooks instead of `connect` method.

```js
import './App.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { products } = useSelector(rootState => rootState.products)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch.products.loadProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log(products)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**Be careful with hooks, you're forgetting to add the deps array to useEffect, any code you add there will run infinitely**

Your Rematch models looks fine, you just need to work more on React essentials :)

Comment: The issue was fixed by changing the name of the model, as both, model and state were called the same

Answer (score 0):

Redux rematch

1. Create music listing app using youtube api
2. How to create folder structure and setup store for react redux

Working code sandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/rematch-yf77l0?file=/src/pages/musics/index.jsx